# nginx redirects does not work with serviceworker

Tags: javascript, nginx, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, nginx-reverse-proxy

We have a serviceworker & a nginx as a front.

For somebody that has never visited the page and therefor doesnt have the serviceworker installed the redirects gets resolved in nginx & therefor goes to client with the correct url. However if an user that has the serviceworker active goes to google and clicks a link to lets say .../a/b which should be redirected to /b/c the service worker picks up before and the user does not get redirected.

Has anyone has this problem & how did you solve it?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because the SW is by default configured to treat such URLs as part of the app and serve `index.html` instead. If you want it to not treat specific URLs as part of your app (and instead let them through to the server), you can change [navigationUrls](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#navigationurls) in the config.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but this is not solution in our case. We have 16 countries with 150 localized legacy urls for each. So we will end up with 2k url. It will be better either you will not cache 301 urls either (even better) add callback hook to ServiceWorkerModule.register with requests or/and response comming so we can decide cache it or not.

Comment: It is not caching them. And it doesn't see the 301.You can use globs to bring down the necessary patterns.

Comment: as i described above there no patterns just pure legacy urls

Comment: Maybe there is pattern in the new URLs (you can have both positive and negative patterns). Other than that, I don't think there is anything we can do :(

Comment: No, there is no pattern. And yes you can do good thing - if you add call function to ServiceWorker.add function which gets response and returns boolean to decide to cache or not then it could cover 100% cases.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What is `ServiceWorker.add`. You could manually patch the service worker script, but even so, how would the function decide which URLs need to be passed through to the server?

Comment: I mean if you ability to provide cache filter function to ```ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production, shouldCacheResponse: (respons: Response) =>  true}),``` options then developer have full control over caching decisions. And yes either you need to provide those urls OR you can take other decisions like look at response headers like 301 or take any other actions to decide cache it or not. Does that makes sense?

Comment: As I mentioned before, the SW does not cache them. It does not see the responses, because these requests never reach the server. The SW serves `index.html` instead, in ordr to support client-side routing (SPA-style). It is the equivalent of configuring your HTTP server to rewrite certain requests to `index.html`.

Comment: So i do not get it then: 
1) First time while app is not loaded and SW is not registered requests passes through and gets 301
2) Once SW is regsitered requests are not passed through and get served with index.html 

so who caches it or how SW behaves that it does not pass this request through?

Comment: Typically, in an SPA, when you navigate to `/foo/bar`, your server serves `index.html`, which loads your app, which imthen takes over and serves the `foo/bar` route (because routing happens on the client side). In order for your app to work offline, the SW has to deal with such requests in a similar manner. By default, the SW recognizes such paths (i.e. paths with no extension in last path segment) as app navigation requests and serves `index.html` (which is expected to load your app and handle the routing on the client-side).

Comment: In contrast, requests with a file extension (such as `my-script.js`), are considered resources and thus served as such (either from cache - if available - or passed through to the server).

Comment: Now, because there are cases where you might want to exclude (or include) other URLs, the SW allows configuring them via `navigationUrls`. For reference, here is our list of `navigationUrls` for https://angular.io: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/73dcd72afbd782161c1674f1e647a1b357a78a67/aio/ngsw-config.json#L72-L129

Comment: @gkalpak can you help with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66016452/angular-9-pwa-social-login-redirects-issue-on-start-url-index-page