# Angular 9 PWA social login redirects issue on start_url / index page

Tags: angular, heroku, progressive-web-apps, cloudflare

I have angular application is running on Angular 9 with SSR & PWA. It runs on  Heroku+ cloudflare.

When I try to login via Facebook/Google on the index page, the angular gives a request timeout error.

Example:

- open index page, https://coursesity.com
- perform social login
- it redirects to https://coursesity.com/?token=avafafdaregasafag
- the Angular gives a timeout error.
- User can't login

But if I perform social login, with other pages that has URL+prefix, it works without any error.

example:

- open https://coursesity.com/section/development
- perform social login
- it redirects to https://coursesity.com/section/development/?token=avafafdaregasafag
- user login successful.

Before implementing PWA and service worker, it was working well.

What can be the problem here? especially for the index page.

**ngsw-config.json**

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/*.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ],
        "urls": [
          "https://fonts.googleapis.com/**"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }],
    "dataGroups": [
      {
        "name": "api",
        "urls": ["/api/**"],
        "cacheConfig": {
          "strategy": "freshness",
          "maxSize": 20,
          "maxAge": "1h",
          "timeout": "5s"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

**Manifest.json**

```
  "name": "Coursesity",
  "short_name": "Coursesity",
  "description": "https://coursesity.com",
  "theme_color": "#5e5e9a",
  "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/?utm_source=a2hs",
  "start_url": "/?ref=pwa",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/images/favicon/logo-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/favicon/logo-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/favicon/logo-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look, this seems related to having SSR change `index.html` after the app has been built. You can infer this by the error seen in `/ngsw/state` (see [here](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#debugging-the-angular-service-worker) for more details on Angular SW debugging APIs):

```
Driver state: EXISTING_CLIENTS_ONLY (Degraded due to: Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork): https://coursesity.com/index.html: expected 4e46d6b5588a4b7358aa32d9240776f02de026c5, got 8c24eec826b40fd30b5c17973a851ffe2f65f4a8 (after cache busting)
Error: Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork): https://coursesity.com/index.html: expected 4e46d6b5588a4b7358aa32d9240776f02de026c5, got 8c24eec826b40fd30b5c17973a851ffe2f65f4a8 (after cache busting)
    at PrefetchAssetGroup.<anonymous> (https://coursesity.com/ngsw-worker.js:96:123)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (https://coursesity.com/ngsw-worker.js:55:98))
Latest manifest hash: 59971a1ef1069cc04a945808cc5f4fc4a1e1a85b
Last update check: 3m31s602u
```

In a nutshell, the SW calculates hashes for all assets (i.e. files) after the build. These hashes are stored in `ngsw.json` (which is generated based on `ngsw-config.json`). When it fetches the files, it hashes them again and compare the actual hashes with the ones stored in `ngsw.json`.

If the hashes do not match, it knows it cannot trust its config and enters a degraded mode (where it does not serve new clients).

---

It sounds like the way you have set up building the app and SSR ends up modifying `index.html` after the SW has calculated its hash and stored it in `ngsw.json`.

A simple work-around could be re-building the SW manifest (`ngsw.json`) after you are done modifying `index.html` with the following command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/ngsw-config /path/to/dist/directory /path/to/ngsw-config.json
```

---

Lastly, let me say that (if you are using the Angular CLI) the default PWA and SSR setup should work out of the box. If that is not the case, I would be happy to take a closer look if you could provide a minimal reproduction (e.g. repo I can check and build to see the problem myself).

Comment: I debuged the issue further and found out, the cookie is not set on index page.  when I run the same thing in the localhost, the cookie is set. 


On production, it is not working. This is more like an issue of Heroku or cloudflare. 

token saved: https://imgur.com/uckon0O
token not saved: https://imgur.com/dkYqoSb